# Google Search Console API Domain permission

Tags: php, google-search-api

I need the ranking for a specific domain in relation to a Keyword.
I guess this should be possible with the Google Search API (PHP).

My Problem: 
I get this error every Time I try to receive the Data:

> User does not have sufficient permission for site ""

I used this Method https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth
to authenticate the access. I have added the Domain in the Google Developer Console and confirmed the Domain successfully. 
I can request data via the Google Search Console Test API Tool without an error but not via the PHP Lib in my project. 
I have tried a lot (other Domains, authenticate with a Service Account, other Google Account, etc) and read some posts with the same Problem but unfortunately without a solution.

Any Ideas what could be the problem or a Link with a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the following scopes while getting the access token:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters ,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly

You can also read about scopes here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: Thanks for the fast Answers.
I have added the scopes already, but the error still exists.

Comment: Have you tried hitting api using POSTMAN?

Comment: ok, nevermind, i got it!
It's a little bit embarrassing..
I have forgotten to add the ServiceAccount email to the Property-Users in my webmaster tool for my Website. 
No Wonder that the authorization got blocked. 

But Thank you very much for your Time!!

Comment: That's wasn't embarassing. We miss things sometimes. I am upvpting your comment so that others may find it helpful.